# Is there any way to ask Weld SE to inject a specific implementation at a given time?

Tags: weld

I use Weld SE in an application, in my application I have an interface for which I have 3 implementations but this causes an ambiguity for Weld. As far as I can see Weld ambiguity resolution technics are static, this can be done by mean of: @specialize, @alternative, @Named or using Qualifier. but this doesn't help me. I need to be able specify a given class implementation of the interface for each case.

I couldn't figure out a solution for my requirement.

Here is a code that illustrates my point

```
public class Foo {
    @Inject
    MyInterface target;
    public void doSomething() {
        target.doIt();
    }
}

public class Bar1 implements MyInterface {    
    public void doIt() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}

public class Bar2 implements MyInterface {  
    public void doIt() {
        System.out.println("Goodbye");
    }

}


public class FooMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Weld weld = new Weld();
        final WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
        Foo foo1 = container.instance().select(Foo.class).get();
        Foo foo2 = container.instance().select(Foo.class).get();
    }
}
```

This code causes this exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type MyInterface with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject com.lodh.arte.test.cdi.Foo.target
  at com.lodh.arte.test.cdi.Foo.target(Foo.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - Managed Bean [class com.lodh.arte.test.cdi.Bar2] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class com.lodh.arte.test.cdi.Bar1] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
```

I need to dynamically tell Weld which implementation to use for injection, just like in this imaginary method Weld.use:

```
 Weld.use ( MyInterface.class, Bar1.class);
 Foo foo1 = container.instance().select(Foo.class).get();
 Weld.use ( MyInterface.class, Bar2.class);
 Foo foo2 = container.instance().select(Foo.class).get();
```

Thank you for your help

Regards

Nader

Answer (score 1):

First you have two implementations of `MyInterface`. `Bar1` and `Bar2`. Weld does not know which implementation to choose when injecting `MyInterface`, so it throws this "Ambiguous dependencies" error.
To avoid this error you should give your implementation different qualifiers.

You have to Qualify your implementations first:

```
@MyQualifier1
public class Bar1 implements MyInterface {
(...)
}

@MyQualifier2
public class Bar2 implements MyInterface {
(...)
}
```

This will allow to inject a specific implementation like this:

```
@Inject
@MyQualifier1
MyInterface target;
```

Now you're injecting an `MyInterface` qualified with `@MyQualifier1`. At runtime its Type will be `Bar1` in this case.

Another approach if you want to decide at runtime which implementation you need would be the use of `Instance`:

```
@Inject
Instance<MyInterface> unqualifiedInstance;

void do(){
    /// first attach the qualifier, we missed at the injection-point:
    Instance qualifiedInstance = instance.select(new AnnotationLiteral<MyQualifier2>(){})
    /// Now you have a qualified Instance, which is a new Object without touching the unqualifiedInstance!
    MyInterface target = qualifiedInstance.get();
    /// so you can decide which implementation you need by passing the qualifier per select-method. in this case its bar2
    target.doIt();
}
```

If you need further help with qualifiers you may find the weld documentation and especially chapter 4.3 and the following helpful.
http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/injection.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Unfortunately I can't change the code to use Instance.
Going through so many site on Weld / CDI I couldn't figure out a dynamic way to do the job. Injection seems to be  determined at class loading time.

Comment: I read you initial post once again. So if I understand your needs correctly you want to tell the weld to use ONLY ONE of the implementations when initializing the weld-environment. So that weld now only uses you desired implementation for all injects of your interface right? If not, could you please explain what else do you need?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. No I need to tell Weld at any moment of time which implementation to use starting from the current time. It is especially required for tests that uses CDI. For one test I want Bar1 for another test I need Bar2.